# How to get all table names from MySQL in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I think its a simple problem, still I don't know how to do it. In one of my projects, I need to get the `names of all tables` in my `database`, in `CakePHP`. Can you guys please help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you just do something like (assuming you are in a controller)? I think it should work

```
$tables = $this->ModelName->query('SHOW TABLES');
pr($tables)
```